# Magento Admin Create Orders

Tags: php, magento

I’m wanting to make the admin create order process more easier for my client. What I’d like to do is, have a new button somewhere i.e. Dashboard, or the orders screen.. Then when they click, it will go straight into the ordering screen bypassing the customer and store selection screen.

We can setup a defualt customer for it to select, so for example we create a new button called ‘InStore1’ this will automatically select customer id3 and store id2 and go straight into the order creation screen.

Is this possible? If so, could somebody point me in the right direction of creating a button to do it...

Cheers

Comment: Nothing just yet, been researching but can't find a way to do it, just wondering if somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That is very possible.

(Did I answer the question completely? Did I miss anything?)

Comment: Well, I was more asking for help on how to create the button!